# apacheのmod_perl2で、リクエスト間で共通の値を保持しておきたい

Tags: perl

apacheでmod_perl2を使用して、リクエストのアクセス制御を行うことを考えています。

以下のように PerlAccessHandler で、サーバローカルのファイルを読み込み、その情報を
元にユーザアクセスの制御したいと思います。

```
=== httpd.conf ===
<Location />
  PerlAccessHandler Hoge::Foo　←ここで処理
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

ただ、リクエストを受ける毎にファイル読み込みを行っていては負荷がかかると思いますので、
一度読み込んだ内容はメモリに保持しておき、ファイル読み込みは100リクエストに一回とする
など、読み込み回数を抑えたいと考えています。

しかし、現状ではリクエストを受けるたびに初期化されてしまうようで、メモリに保持する
ことができていません。

何かリクエスト間で共通して値を保持しておけるよい方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

共有メモリを使ったプロセス間通信をすると良さそうです。
Perlだとこんなの↓があったので試してみてはいかがでしょう。
http://search.cpan.org/~andya/IPC-ShareLite-0.17/lib/IPC/ShareLite.pm

Comment: 確かにうまくいきました。ありがとうございます。mod_perlを使えば、スクリプトがメモリに保持され、変数の値も保存されると読んだことがあるのですが、この場合には当てはまらないのでしょうか。

Comment: あまり詳しくないのでぐぐってみましたが メモリにキャッシュするのは `ModPerl::Registry` の機能らしいで `PerlAccessHandler` では使えないのかなという気がします。ただ識者の方にも意見がもらえたらと思いますので、もしよろしければ新規の質問として投稿してみてください。